# Rails 4 ActiveRecords: Save multiple records at once with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hi i have the following situation. I can save this array of hashes

```
products = [{
   :name=> 0,
   :key  => 12345,
   :label => "test1",
  },{
   :name=> 0,
   :key  => 12145,
   :label => "test",    
  }]
```

at once with

```
products.map {|p| Product.new(p).save }
```

or

```
Product.create(products)
Product.create!(products)
```

but the all my uniqueness validations like

```
validates :key, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

are ignored, using the rails console. I am able to save this hash multiple times. Does anyone has some advice? Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

As simple as restarting my rails console. After that my logs look like the logs from @Akadisoft.

Also using this way:

```
products.map {|p| Product.new(p).save }
```

which return an array with booleans `[false,true]` either the record was saved or not, which is nice for further evaluation.

Comment: Could you show the exact commands and output you used in rails console?

Comment: Are you sure that the records are actually saved? Please add the save transaction.

Comment: can you post your model and db migration?

Comment: The logs showed that the records were again saved violating the constraints. I needed to reload the console, even i added the validations BEFORE starting the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your exact solution and everything works as intented..

The first time I ran the command `Product.create(products)` I have the following result

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 1, key: "12345", name: 0, label: "test1", created_at: "2015-12-09 19:21:01", updated_at: "2015-12-09 19:21:01">, #<Product id: 2, key: "12145", name: 0, label: "test", created_at: "2015-12-09 19:21:01", updated_at: "2015-12-09 19:21:01">]>
```

We can see that it created two products (`id`:1 and `id`:2).

Now the second I run the exact same command here is the result:

```
[#<Product id: nil, key: "12345", name: 0, label: "test1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Product id: nil, key: "12145", name: 0, label: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
irb(main):015:0>
```

We can see the ID is `nil` because it didn't save the products. I can also see in the console output that DB transaction were rollbacked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on console and it only added one record.

```
14:42 $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.2.2 :001 > products = [{:key =>1},{:key=>1}]
 => [{:key=>1}, {:key=>1}] 
2.2.2 :002 > products.map {|p| Product.new(p).save }
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."key" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("key", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["key", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-09 19:42:32.488255"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-09 19:42:32.488255"]]
   (0.4ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."key" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
 => [true, false] 
2.2.2 :003 > Product.all
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 1, key: 1, created_at: "2015-12-09 19:42:32", updated_at: "2015-12-09 19:42:32">]>
```